# I need to create a backspace function for my calculator with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm programming a simple calculator with javascript, and I'm finding it hard to make a correct backspace function.

When the backspace button is clicked, I want it to remove the last character on the screen.

NB: I know I'm nowhere close to the correct solution, I'm a newbie, so go easy on me :D.

Here's my code:

```js
// Clear and backspace  
            
            function clearAll() {
                if (control){
                    lastScreen = screenView.value;
                    screenView.value = 0;
                    alert("cleared!");
                }
            }
            
            function backSpace() {
                if (control) {
                    var newScreenView = [];
                    if (screenView.value != 0) {
                        screenViewLength = screenView.value.length;
                        for (i = 0; i < screenViewLength; i++) {
                            newScreenView.push(screenView.value[i]);
                        }
                        remove = newScreenView.length ;
                        console.log(newScreenView[remove]);
                        //screenView.value = newScreenView;
                    }
                
                alert("backspace");
                }
            }
```

```
<input type="button" id="backspace_button" onclick="backSpace()" value="<="/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just slice the string

`screenView.value = screenView.value.slice(0, screenView.value.length -1)`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function backSpace(){
    screenView.value = screenView.value.slice(0, - 1);
}
```

One liner right there!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `substr` method:

```
screenView.value = screenView.value.substr(0, screenView.value.length - 1)
```

But if you hold the user input in a `buffer`:

```
buffer.pop()
screenView.value = buffer.join('')
```